# "Missing control sequence" when labeling a section within the argument using revtex4-2

Tags: labels, revtex

I am using TexStudio and just updated from TexLive 2020 to TexLive 2022. The error

> Missing control sequence inserted. \section{The first section
> \label{sec}}

occurs when trying to compile my old tex files with **revtex4-2**. (The compiling of these files are perfectly OK before with TexLive 2020, and I do not change anything.)

For example, such an error occurs when I try to compile:

```
\documentclass[english]{revtex4-2}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}

\section{The first section \label{sec}}
\subsection{The first subsection \label{subsec}}

\ref{sec}
\ref{subsec}

\end{document}
```

I have tried:

```
\section{The first section} \label{sec}
```

which is OK. Or if I change to other documentclasses (e.g.) **article**, it is also OK.

Strangely, `\subsection{...\label{...}}` and `\subsubsection{...\label{...}}` do not show this error at all, which only occur for `\section{...\label{...}}`.

I am not sure what the problem is. Since I used `\section{...\label{...}}` in all my old tex files with **revtex4-2**, so it is not possible to change it to `\section{...}\label{...}` by hand.

Comment: You can use `\protect\label``

Comment: https://github.com/latex3/babel/issues/193

Comment: Thanks David! So it is a bug of the latest babel? But then it also means no solution "globally" (instead of changing each tex file by hand) at this moment?

Comment: you could use \robustfy from etoolnox to make \label obust